# Alsa ok, but no audio from Jack

Tags: lubuntu, jack

So I run `qjackctl` and click start. It shows no errors, but there is no sound at all from any application. When I stop `qjackctl` it all starts working.

I have no idea how to debug this :(

Specs: HP Compaq 6715s, Lubuntu 14.04.1 LTS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to your connections first need to be configured look alike:

and [other screenshots is here](http://qjackctl.sourceforge.net/qjackctl-ss1.html)

[image: qjackctl Patchbay]

**about [configuration](http://qjackctl.sourceforge.net/#Configuration)**

> QjackCtl holds its settings and configuration state per user, in a file located as
>
> ```
>     $HOME/.config/rncbc.org/QjackCtl.conf
> ```
>
> Normally, there's no need to edit this file, as it is recreated and
>   rewritten every time `qjackctl` is run.